# Is there a way to add a method to built-in/native powershell object (or type?/class¿)?

Tags: powershell, object, syntax, hashtable

Is there a way to add a method to built-in/native powershell object (or type?/class¿)?

In particular, I'm looking at you `[hashtable]`, but I suppose my question is also a general one...  for instance, I could see wanting to add functionality to all my arrays...

For instance, I would like all my `[hashtable]` objects to have the method:  `.AddAndOverwrite(..)` which would replace the value of the key if it exists; otherwise it creates a new key.

The only way I seem to be able to do this is to:

1. create an empty `hashtable`, `$HashTableNew`
2. add the `ScriptMethod`(s) to `$HashTableNew` (i.e. `.AddAndOverwrite(..)`)
3. then when I use it, make a copy of `$HashTableNew`

> - `$SomeOtherHashTable = $HashTableNew.PSObject.Copy()`

This just seems like not "*the way*"...

***Note:***  I will admit, this is not the best example use of a data type extension method (as @SantiagoSquarzon points out)...  but it is a simple one, and it allows for a simple example in the accepted answer; so I'm intentionally leaving it as is, rather than changing question / the extension method to `.foo()` returning `widgets`...

Comment: Why do you need a class for this when you can do it with an `if` condition ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon this is just an example of a helper method I'd like to add (and not all of them)...  and because I think an if statement for every time I want to `AddOverwrite` to a `hashtable` is alot of code duplication when I could encapsulate that functionality into 'how' the hashtables work (or arrays, etc).

Comment: I think you need to add a visual representation of what you mean

Comment: `$HashTableNew['mykey'] = 'myvalue'` will add a new key/value pair if it doesn't exist and, replace the value of the key if it does exist.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon while I appreciate your feedback (& sharing of a solution to the admittedly bad example for a data type extension method) ... what the example did wasn't the point (I should have just said extension method `.foo()` returning `widgets`...  as you can see in SagePourpre's accepted answer, what I was really after was how to modify PowerShell intrinsic data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a better and easier way to update a type as a whole by using `Update-TypeData`.

Here is an example that add an `.AddOrOverwrite` method to the hashtable.

```
$TypeParam = @{
    TypeName = 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
    MemberType = 'ScriptMethod'
    MemberName = 'AddOrOverwrite'
    Value      = { Param($Key, $Value) $this.$key = $Value }
}

Update-TypeData @TypeParam -Force

$SomeHashTable.AddOrOverwrite('aaa','2222222')
```

`$this`, in the scriptblock of the method definition, correspond to the object reference that is targeted, in this case, the hashtable.

`-Force` will overwrite the definition every time without error stating the type was already added.

That method is not super useful as it does something that the hashtable manage pretty well on its own by just using assignment but it demonstrates how to do it.

**Bonus example**

Here's an example on how you would apply this principle and create 2 script properties (readonly) for a string so you can convert to base 64 back and forth.

```
$TypeParam = @{
    TypeName   = 'System.String'
    MemberType = 'ScriptProperty'
    Force = $true
}

Update-TypeData @TypeParam -MemberName 'Base64' -Value { [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($this)) }
Update-TypeData @TypeParam -MemberName 'Base64Decoded' -Value { [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($this)) }



# Encode the string to base 64 (Output: U29tZVN0cmluZw==)
"SomeString".Base64
# Decode the string from Base64 (Output: SomeString)
"U29tZVN0cmluZw==".Base64Decoded
```

**References**

[Msdocs - About-Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.2)

[Dr Scripto - Easily Update Powershell Type Data by Using a Cmdlet](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/easily-update-powershell-type-data-by-using-a-cmdlet/)

Comment: The bonus example is a nice example of using `Update-TypeData`; I appreciate the thoroughness of your answer, it was exactly what I was looking for!